# If you sacrifice yourself on The Sacrifice in expert realism mode, do you get the "Real Deal" achievement?

Tags: left-4-dead-2

The title says it all. But i'll describe further.

You are playing The Sacrifice in Left 4 Dead 2. You are playing realism mode on the expert level. You hope to get the Real Deal achievement, which involves "surviving a campaign on expert difficulty with realism mode enabled."

You sacrifice yourself (as someone has to) to complete the campaign.

Do you get "The Real Deal"?

Comment: further food for thought - what if "surviving" means "completing the campaign," codewise? Don't you get the "Supreme Sacrifice" achievement for completing the campaign even if you're the sacrifice? (as i recall, only the sacrifice got "supreme sacrifice" but i think that was a bug. the way it reads, the whole team should get it if one person sacrifices and the rest are on the bridge)

Comment: Do you get it even if you don't sacrifice yourself?  I thought that achievement was only for the original campaigns, with a full 5 levels?

Comment: I only got "Supreme Sacrifice" once I sacrificed myself. But there is a completion achievement for the passing which is only 3 levels ("Torch Bearer"). Every single campaign has a completion achievement, which is why I think "Supreme Sacrifice" is buggy.

Answer (score 1):

No. 
Well, that shouldn't come as a surprise, since you don't exactly fulfill the "surviving" part.

It's your funeral, so, you're an acceptable casualty :)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I agree with your logic, but did you test or see this tested?

Comment: I already had the achievement as I played through the campaign, and I sacrificed myself, and my name was in the "in memory of" list. So that is proof enough for me.